# iOS extension- sharing bubble vs sharing button?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-app-extension

I have read the apple docs about app extensions- sharing

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ShareSheet.html

What they say is that when an host app has a sharing button , you can choose your app extension to share content .

But it seems that there is another sharing option that is not in the docs, and i cant figure out whats the different and how you enable this extension.

When you mark any text in `ibooks` ,or `Safari` , there is a little bubble opened with `copy, past, select all, and share.` 
there if you hit the **share** button, you prompt with apps extensions, and you can share that highlighted text with the extension .

So, questions are :

1. the highlighted text sharing- is it enabled in every app that lets you to highlight any text ?
2. How you enable this extension, and is it the same as the regular sharing extension? (where you have a button  with a rect and an arrow). Developing an app with sharing extension would be relevant to both cases ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , it seems that the sharing extension is working with the "bubble" sharing button , but with the regular sharing button(a rect and an arrow) you get as an input -a link to the page, much as Pocket do .

So software speaking its the same, functionality is different.